# Creating separated files for each request with createWriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm making multiple `URL` request's using `Axios` and collecting the data using `Cheerio`.
Everything works great, I just can't figure out how to prevent the data to be overwritten by the previous `response` that was generated into a file using the `createWriteStream` method.

I'm trying to create different files for each request with unique names preferably, but haven't found any solution in the docs.

```
const axios = require("axios").default;
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./names/names.text')

const getTitle = (res) => {
   const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
   const names = $('.name_wrap > .name')

   names.each(function (i, el) {
      const item = $(el).text().replace(/^\s*$/g, '')
      writeStream.write(`${item}\n`)
   });
}

// URL'S Array
let URLS = []

for (let index = 1; index <= 3; index++) {
   let url = `https://www.example.com/name-1-${index}`
   URLS.push(axios.get(url))
}

Promise.all(URLS)
   .then(responses => {
      getTitle(responses[0])
      getTitle(responses[1])
   });
```

Comment: In order to achieve this, you can create writeStream in `getTitle` function instead creating one global stream.

Comment: @Raeesaa Thanks. I'v tried this approach, but it created a file for each individual title
 not for every URL request.